# PHP how to dynamically instantiate a class

Tags: php, class, dynamic, instantiation

I am new to PHP, and I tried to dynamically instantiate a class like this:

```
$var = new \App\$str;
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
unexpected  variable $str after '\', expected: identifier.
```

I know it is possible, but I am just not sure what the exact syntax is, all the examples I found are without the `\App\` part which I need.

Comment: try this `$var = new \App\{$str};`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `new` operator accepts either a class name identifier, or a variable containing a class name, but not a mixture of them.

Since a part of your fully qualified class name is unknown (dynamic), you should put all the parts into a string variable:

```
$class_name = 'A';
$namespace = '\\App';
$fully_qualified_class_name = "$namespace\\$class_name";
$var = new $fully_qualified_class_name;
```